# rgdal::writeOGR collision in column names results in NULL data

Tags: shapefile, r, export

I already know ([How to stop writeOGR from abbreviating Field Names when using “ESRI Shapefile” driver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30785/how-to-stop-writeogr-from-abbreviating-field-names-when-using-esri-shapefile-d)) that writeOGR is abbreviating names of columns longer than 10 chars. But there is one more thing. If some two column names are same in case-insensitive way, it will remove data from both/one of them!

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
line.data.df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, Aa = 3, bB=4, aa = "hello", bb = "bug" , Depth.Stratum.max = 6, Depth.Stratum.min =3)
l <- rgeos::readWKT("LINESTRING(0 7,1 6,2 1,3 4,4 1,5 7,6 6,7 4,8 6,9 4)")
l.df <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl = l, data = line.data.df)
writeOGR(obj =l.df, dsn = ".",  layer = "test_abbreviation", driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = T)
l.shp <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "test_abbreviation")
l.shp@data
```

With output

```
> library(rgeos)
rgeos version: 0.3-23, (SVN revision 546)
 GEOS runtime version: 3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246 
 Linking to sp version: 1.2-5 
 Polygon checking: TRUE 

> library(rgdal)
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.2-8, (SVN revision 663)
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01
 Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/2.1
 Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 492]
 Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
 Linking to sp version: 1.2-5 
> library(sp)
> line.data.df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, Aa = 3, bB=4, aa = "hello", bb = "bug" , Depth.Stratum.max = 6, Depth.Stratum.min =3)
> l <- rgeos::readWKT("LINESTRING(0 7,1 6,2 1,3 4,4 1,5 7,6 6,7 4,8 6,9 4)")
> l.df <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl = l, data = line.data.df)
> writeOGR(obj =l.df, dsn = ".",  layer = "temp.samplings", driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = T)
Warning message:
In writeOGR(obj = l.df, dsn = ".", layer = "temp.samplings", driver = "ESRI Shapefile",  :
  Field names abbreviated for ESRI Shapefile driver
> l.shp <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "temp.samplings")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: ".", layer: "temp.samplings"
with 1 features
It has 8 fields
> l.shp@data
  a b Aa bB aa_1 bb_1 Dpth_Strtm Dpth_Str_1
0 1 2  0  0 <NA> <NA>         NA         NA
```

You can see that strange and annoying abbreviation + case-insensitivity caused columns (especially my *Depth.Stratum.min* and *Depth.Stratum.max*) to have colliding names resulting in data loss. 
Weird:

1. some letters in names are kept in UPPER case.
2. in case of columns (*aa* and *aA*) - data from one of them was preserved, in case of my columns *Depth.Stratum.min* and *Depth.Stratum.max* none contained original data

Is this behavior a bug or it's just something I have to live with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the shapefile specification https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf which .dbf version is used for the attributes but it may be dBase IV version. The older versions of dbf have strict limits for the field names. This http://www.okstate.edu/sas/v8/sashtml/accpc/z0214453.htm may not be the most official document but it makes clear that naming conventions have been changing even by the operating system

> DBF File Naming Conventions
>
> Filenames must also follow operating-system specific conventions, so
>   check the documentation that comes with your dBASE product or other
>   software products for further information. The following conventions
>   apply to DBF filenames and field names:
>
> Under Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows NT, and OS/2, the ACCESS and DBLOAD procedures support long names that are specified in the PATH=
>   statement (such as path='c:\sasdemo\library\customer99.dbf';) However,
>   some applications that support dBASE files might not accept files with
>   long names.
>
> Filenames or field names start with a letter, and they can contain any combination of the letters A through Z, the digits 0 through 9,
>   the colon (:) (in dBASE II field names only), and the underscore (_).
>
> Database field names can be from one to ten characters long. Each field in a DBF file has a unique name.
>
> Filenames or field names are not case sensitive; that is, CUSTOMER is the same as Customer. Field names typed in lowercase are changed to
>   uppercase on the display.

How the GDAL shapefile driver is renaming the fields is documented in http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html. Your case feels like a bug because GDAL tries to create unique names like in the example

```
a → a, a → a_1, A → A_2;
```

However, why to rely on the automatic renaming when you can take the full control and rename the fields yourself in the source data?

I made a test with ogr2ogr and it seems that it does better job than your code.

Create a csv file

```
a,b,Aa,bB,aa,bb,Depth.Stratum.max,Depth.Stratum.min
1,2,3,4,"hello","bug",6,3
```

Check with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo fieldnametest.csv -al
INFO: Open of `fieldnametest.csv'
      using driver `CSV' successful.

Layer name: fieldnametest
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
a: String (0.0)
b: String (0.0)
Aa: String (0.0)
bB: String (0.0)
aa: String (0.0)
bb: String (0.0)
Depth.Stratum.max: String (0.0)
Depth.Stratum.min: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(fieldnametest):1
  a (String) = 1
  b (String) = 2
  Aa (String) = hello
  bB (String) = bug
  Depth.Stratum.max (String) = 6
  Depth.Stratum.min (String) = 3
```

Convert into shapefile (dbf)

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" fieldnametest.shp fieldnametest.csv
Warning 1: Field 'aa' already exists. Renaming it as 'aa2'
Warning 1: Field 'bb' already exists. Renaming it as 'bb2'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'Depth.Stratum.max' to 'Depth.Stra'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'Depth.Stratum.min' to 'Depth.St_1'
```

Check the result

```
ogrinfo fieldnametest.dbf -al
INFO: Open of `fieldnametest.dbf'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: fieldnametest
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2017-09-12
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
a: String (80.0)
b: String (80.0)
Aa: String (80.0)
bB: String (80.0)
aa2: String (80.0)
bb2: String (80.0)
Depth.Stra: String (80.0)
Depth.St_1: String (80.0)
OGRFeature(fieldnametest):0
  a (String) = 1
  b (String) = 2
  Aa (String) = 3
  bB (String) = 4
  aa2 (String) = hello
  bb2 (String) = bug
  Depth.Stra (String) = 6
  Depth.St_1 (String) = 3
```