# Coercing to sp and dealing with duplicate field names

Tags: r, sp, sf

I am dealing with a very similar situation as described at:

[rgdal::writeOGR collision in column names results in NULL data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255082/rgdalwriteogr-collision-in-column-names-results-in-null-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have an sf object with duplicate field names (in a case-insensitive way). Coercing to sp with `as(foo, "Spatial")` does not do any sanitizing  and this breaks downstream processing.

The errors I get are variously:

> ERROR: Cannot insert new row: insert into `foo` values ( 1, 55800, )
>
> Failed to create feature

Is there an automated solution other than manually checking for dups and renaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try with [data janitor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/janitor.pdf)'s function `clean_names()`